# Where is edit history visible?

Tags: discussion, editing

For those with rating either above or below 2k, is there a place one can see the edits on a post? So far, no see 'um.

Answer (score 6):

All edits are visible to *all* users.

[image]

If you click on the text in that red free hand circle ("Edited x hours ago"), it will take you to the revision history of the post. If that text isn't there then there are no stored revisions.

Comment: Okay. In a recent case I saw comments deleted. (I actually encouraged someone --- mod or poster-- to delete them.) but out of nostalgia sake, I was wondering if the deleted comments were available to anyone.

Comment: @pterandon no, deleted comments are mod only.

Comment: @waxeagle Oh, they finally got that in for you guys. That is new right? They used to be gone forever, even from mods.

Comment: @fredsbend: Correct. For several months now, mods have been able to see deleted comments, and more recently, even undelete comments.

Comment: I guess what I'm really getting at is that I made a conciliatory "You're both right" comment, even as I requested deletion of the bickering comments. I'm just wondering what are the chances that the bickering parties saw my comment, which was also deleted.